# Разметить RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adapter

Всем доброго дня. Задача следующая: Есть фрагмент, внутри которого есть RecyclerView с некоторым списком item'ов. В каждом item могут быть вложены свои item'ы. Отображение родительского RecyclerView я реализовал, а как внутрь элемента в нем добавить свои элементы не пойму. Масло масленое, но суть должна быть ясна. может кто сталкивался? Или есть другие решения для данной задачи?

Comment: в каждом айтеме будет горизонтальный ресайклер и в адаптере вы туда добавляете данные

Answer (score 1):

Создаете RecyclerView в котором в качестве элемента адаптера является макет с RecyclerView. Вам нужно будет написать свой второй адаптер для внутреннего RecyclerView и его отдельно биндить.

Дальше передаете в основной RecyclerView список списков данных или же пишете какие-то кастомные методы для передачи данных для списков отдельно.

Но тут есть много подводных камней. Например вы скролите один список - нажимаете на элемент - проваливаетесь в детали - возвращаетесь обратно, а место где вы были во внутреннем списке сбрасывается. Вам надо это контролировать.

Вам придется прокидывать кликлистенеры через 2 адаптера, а это не очень красиво да и чревато багами.

Есть и другие моменты с которыми вы обязательно столкнетесь. Поэтому я рекомендую вам хорошенько подумать, а надо ли вам делать это именно так?

Проще работать если вы к примеру добавите нужное вам кол-во RecyclerView в ScrollView (хотя и тут не все красиво). Если конечно их там не 100 шт.

Или как вариант сделать каждый RecyclerView отдельным фрагментов и сделать ScrollView в котором будут фрагменты с RecyclerView. Так вы каждый Recycler инкапсулирете в отдельный контейнер, который сам будет обрабатывать всю работу со списком.

Ну что бы вы не выбрали, это не оч простое решение будет.

Comment: @sergey я создал фрагмент, главный макет, в котором есть RecyclerView, создал айтем, в котором также есть RecyclerView. Есть адаптер для первого списка (adapter1), есть адаптер для второго (adapter2). Во фрагменте указал, что для элемента главного макет соответствует adapter1, тут проблем нет, все работает. Как и где мне обозначить, что для второго списка есть adapter2? В первом адаптере? Тогда возникают проблемы с context. Если во фрагменте - выпадает ошибка, что элемент пустой.